# Creating CSR's using a bat file and OpenSSL

Tags: batch-file, openssl, csr

I've ran into a problem while using a bat file to automatically create a CSR.
Code:
[image]

Which does this:
[image]

Where it says "Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:", it was suppose to put "UK" after the colon.

I believe this is happening because the "@Openssl req -out .csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout .key" initializes the CSR creation and everything after it is not being inputted into the console.

You can see I've even tried timing out the console so once the initialization of the CSR has finished the bat file would carry on inputting the commands but the timeout has been unsuccessful.

How do i fix this?

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16842769/2433843

Comment: i tried and still not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing CSR distinguished-name fields as parameters to OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842768/passing-csr-distinguished-name-fields-as-parameters-to-openssl)